# The jquery $.each function console.log(this) ,prints result is string like "a" 'b' 'c'

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

```
var arr=["aaa","bbb","cccc"];
$.each(arr,function(a,b){
    console.log(this);
})
```

the result is in the Chrome console following :

[image]

the Chrome console

i think the result is "aaa" "bbb","cccc",why the result is "a" "a" "a" 'b''b''b'....

Comment: it is aaa,bbb,cccc only(you can do the alert for this). chrome got different way of showing the string. with extra info

Comment: Use console.log(b); It will print aaa bbb cccc

Comment: thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try change to this:

```
var arr=["aaa","bbb","cccc"];
$.each(arr,function(a,b){
    console.log(b);
})
```

Comment: thanks you , i know the 'console.log(b)' can get the expected result 。
i don‘t understand the "this" .
thanks for your help again .

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that inside your `each` loop, `this` is not scoped for the current element being iterated.

In `JQuery.each()`,
The variable you use as `a` is the iteration index
The Variable you use as `b` is the current iterated element.

If you want to log the current iterated element, use `b` instead of `this`:

```
$.each(arr,function(a,b){
    console.log(b);
                ▲
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The result in your provided image is correct. The console only displays the individual characters of the string and its length information, but if you look at the actual value (the primitive value), it indeed displays "aaa", "bbb", and "cccc".

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=["aaa","bbb","cccc"];

console.log(new String(arr[0]));
console.log(new String(arr[1]));
console.log(new String(arr[2]));
```

when you use the jQuery.each to loop the "arr", the callback while bind to new String(arr[i])

```
$.each(arr,function(a,b){
    console.log(new String(b));
    console.log(this);
})
```

and the param "b" is your expected results